# How to get httpcontext.request as it is in .net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, sha256

I am trying to read request from httpcontext,but it is changing, not same with original request.So it creates problem during hashing on SHA256.When I try to create sha256 on online tools with original request it is okey,but when I take request after reading it from httpcontext.request its is not same hash I create with original request.
What is the exact solution to read request as same as with original request without changing it and convert to string to compute SHA256?

```
              using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await httpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                        {
                            var bodyContent = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);

                           //hashing starts here with bodyContent.ToString()

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: If you can see different hashes for _the same_ request, how about storing both strings as file and compare them in a text editor to find the differences of both strings? If we know that, we can talk about how to avoid them.

Comment: I suggest you compare the two plaintexts. That is the quickest way to see why they are different. You may have to normalize ("[canonicalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization)") the input in some way, e.g. convert CRLF to LF or exclude certain headers, before passing to the hash function.

Comment: Actually,I am getting two json data ,one of them contains null as on some inputs and the other has no null inputs,when I use same method to compute hash256 , the json without null works fine , but the json with null not computing sha256 as expected.

Comment: Which data is from the origin, the one contains null or not.

Comment: Both of them origin,one time they ara sending request with null values,other time they are sending without null values.

Comment: So what's your final goal about your project? Can you tell us? It will help us understand your issue here.